# Vimeo api get hidden video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using Vimeo php library: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

I have created app on Vimeo and generated token and secret.

I can sucessfully retrieve normal video from Vimeo using following:

```
$result = $vimeo->request("/videos/$video_id", array(
        'fields' => 'uri,name,description,download,link,duration',
));
```

However when I try to retrieve which is hidden from Vimeo in privacy settings:  https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Manage-your-video-s-privacy-settings

For example, this video:  https://vimeo.com/354438711

I get 404  {error: "The requested video couldn't be found."}

The same is true if I try in their api explorer:  https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_video

But this is not my video, I am testing video from a client. I dont have plus account to be able to set video privacy to hidden.

My client can get video using api explorer, but not using Vimeo php library.

Is it possible that api cannot retrieve hidden video?